# Is the limit point of a chain necessarily a least upper bound?

Tags: logic, convergence-divergence, set-theory, order-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Let the space $X,d$ have a partial order $\preceq$

Let every infinite chain $x_i\preceq x_{i+1},\ldots$ have a limit point in $X,d$

If every limit point is a least upper bound, then Zorn's Lemma applies and there is at least one maximal element.

But does it follow that every limit point of a partial order is a least upper bound?

Comment: Is $\prec$ compatible with $(X,d)$?  In other words, is the order topology defined by your partial order $\prec$ the same as the metric topology?

Comment: @user10354138 I think yours is a key question.  I'm working on a problem where this *chains converge to a least upper bound* property probably exists, so I think i have to show that the order topology is the same as the metric topology.  Is there more you can tell me about this?

Comment: If the metric topology is the same as the order topology (or finer), then it follows that, for any net $a\colon I\to X$, $a_i\preceq b$ (for all $i$) implies $\lim a_i\preceq b$ and similar.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following order on the real numbers from $0$ to $1$. The restriction on the set or rational (irrational) numbers is the usual order but every irrational number is smaller than every rational number. Then every infinite sequence has a limit point but the limit point of a chain  can be  smaller than every element of the chain.

Comment: Great counterexample, thanks.

Comment: If no objections, it is better to accept the answer.